# Multiline listing in a table environment

Tags: tables, listings

I'm trying to simulate an effect that is very easy to do in WYSIWYG environments, namely having a table with some cells containing somewhat complex multi-line entities. For instance, consider the following table (created with OpenOffice):

[image: table]

In particular, I'm concerned about the middle cell at the bottom there; I can't find a way to create that in LaTeX using the `table` environment. The problem seems to be that it has no way of distinguishing the `\\` linebreak as referring to the contents of the cell, or to the structure of the table.

I know about the `multirow` package and how it theoretically allows things like this, but only in the clumsiest of ways; I would have to set something like a colspan on every row of that source. If I were to add a line to the beginning of the listing, I'd have to manually shift each row after that down.

What I would love is some sort of easy thing to wrap my code in which makes it all belong to a single table row. I feel certain there must be a way to do that, but Google wasn't being very helpful, so I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `lstlising` environment from `listings` package to replace `verbatim`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\begin{lstlisting}
!@#$%^$%&
!@#$%^$%&
\end{lstlisting}
&
\begin{lstlisting}
!@#$%^$%&
!@#$%^$%&
\end{lstlisting}
\\ \hline
\begin{lstlisting}
!@#$%^$%&
!@#$%^$%&
\end{lstlisting}
&
\begin{lstlisting}
!@#$%^$%&
!@#$%^$%&
\end{lstlisting}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```